# How do I calculate present value of irregular deposits/withdrawals with interest in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to teach my kids to save so I'm giving them the chance to deposit money into a "bank account" that pays interest (that I run).  I'd like to create a spreadsheet to track the current value of their accounts.  This seems like it would be easy but I'm having trouble figuring it out in excel.

Given a worksheet of deposits and withdrawals on various dates - how do I calculate the current value of the accounts assuming a constant interest rate (interest rate never changes)?

- 1/1/2016 +$10
- 1/4/2016 +$4
- 1/10/2016 -$5
- 1/10/2016 +$2
- etc

Current Value with X% interest rate = ???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to state how often the interest is going to be compounded in the account (weekly, quarterly, monthly, yearly).  Most banks now have something like 1% on savings accounts so that won't be hard to beat.  Maybe a nickel a month.  What will I do with my new found wealth?  You will basically average the balances over the time period and multiply it times the interest rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it up like this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/qRQ6dzY.png]

The Contribution is how much they add at a particular date, the Start Balance is the previous End Balance plus the Contribution, and the End Balance is Start Balance plus Interest.

There are different ways to do compounding interest, but I've chosen to compound it daily, which means you take the annual Interest Rate and compute the period interest rate as

```
(1 + Rate)^(Days / 365) - 1
```

where `Days` is the number of days since the last contribution. The Interest amount is this adjusted rate times the Start Balance.

Comment: Wow - this is exactly what I was looking for.  Extra points for making the problem simpler than what I was wrestling with in my head.  Strong work - thanks so much!